# Layout alignment issues android

Tags: android

I have a custom keypad like view in my Activity which looks like this
[image]

Now I want to make the * and = button as a single button like this

[image]

The XML layout for the keypad is

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/keypad_PAYMENT_LL"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amount_PAYMENT_RL">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="+"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_payment_button"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="-"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_payment_button"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="7"
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="8"
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="9"
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_payment_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:text="*"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="C"
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_payment_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="&lt;"
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_payment_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button29"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_payment_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:text="="
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried many times, but not able to achieve. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of **nesting layouts** (which is a BAD thing), you should either use a RelativeLayout or a GridLayout.

Comment: Well, I told you how you **should** do. Layout nesting is something to **avoid**.

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout which contains both buttons "=" and "*" with the size of the second image. Then just use button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) or button.setVisibility(View.GONE) to show or hide a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna stick with the nested `LinearLayouts` (which, as [Frank N. Stein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960379/layout-alignment-issues-android#comment51828529_31960379) mentioned, is not really the best thing to do) you should change your layout a bit.

Currently your root `LinearLayout` is `vertical`, and you're building rows of your keyboard (with inner, `horizontal` `LinearLayouts`).

The root layout should be `horizontal` and you should build your keyboard with inner `vertical` `LinearLayouts` (columns). In that way, you would be able to make your `=` button expand to the size of `=` and `*` simply by changing their weights (`=` should have `android:layout_weight="2"` and `*` should have `android:layout_weight="0"`, if other buttons from this column have `android:layout_weight="1"`).

Comment: Hi, I am following your approach. But now the last column/ vertical layout which contains the * and equal has the problem. I have removed the * button. I just have three buttons in that, while the other vertical layouts have 4. Now I need the first two button's i.e. +,- to be in the height of first two rows. And the = button to stretch all the way down, covering the two rows below. How do I do it ?

Comment: That's why you need to modify `weights`. Set your `+` and `-` `weights` to `1`, and your `=` `weight` to `2`.

Comment: Should I give weightsum for the parent layout ?

Comment: Just giving 1 for +, 1 for 1, 2 for =, makes +,- alone to fill two rows, the = is goes below.

Comment: So? isn't that what you wanted? how does that situation relate to the case you wanted to achieve ("Now I want to make the * and = button as a single button like this")

Comment: No, see the screenshot above, I want the + to cover first row, - to cover second row, = to cover the remaining to rows. But in the case u have said, it becomes like + covers first two rows, - covers next two rows and the = is invisible.

Comment: OK, first of all. The problem is probably not with the approach, but with your `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` parameters. If you have a `vertical` (`horizontal`) `LinearLayout` and you control the `height` (`width`) of your contents with `weights`, you should set `android:layout_height="0dp"` (`android:layout_width="0dp"`) for those content `Views`.

Answer (score 1):

As Frank N.Stein said, using Grid layout was much effective.
Thanks.
This solved my problem.

```
 <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout12"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button22"
        android:useDefaultMargins="false">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/button23"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/button24"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/button25"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"
            android:id="@+id/button26"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/blue_dark" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/button27"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/button28"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/button30"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:id="@+id/button31"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/blue_dark" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/button32"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/button33"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9"
            android:id="@+id/button34"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="="
            android:id="@+id/button35"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/blue_dark" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C"
            android:id="@+id/button36"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/blue_dark" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/button37"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_general_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="&lt;"
            android:id="@+id/button38"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_general"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/blue_dark" />

    </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/keypad_PAYMENT_LL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                android:layout_margin="2dp"

                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                android:layout_margin="2dp"

                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                android:layout_margin="2dp"

                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                android:layout_margin="2dp"

                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                android:layout_margin="2dp"

                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                android:layout_margin="2dp"

                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button9"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"

                        android:layout_weight="1"

                        android:text="7"
                        android:textSize="40sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button10"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                        android:layout_margin="2dp"

                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="8"
                        android:textSize="40sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button11"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                        android:layout_margin="2dp"

                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="9"
                        android:textSize="40sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button13"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"

                        android:layout_weight="1"

                        android:text="C"
                        android:textSize="40sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button14"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                        android:layout_margin="2dp"

                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button13"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button13"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="40sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button15"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                        android:layout_margin="2dp"

                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button14"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button14"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="&lt;"
                        android:textSize="40sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="="
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
             android:layout_weight="1">



             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/button29"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                 android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button15"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button15"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="="
                 android:textSize="40sp" />
         </LinearLayout>-->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is your solution check it if it helps you please add repo.